# Does a Warder with Defensive Focus and Combat Reflexes use Int or Dex?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

In Pathfinder, if a class grants an altered version of a feat that I already have, which takes priority? Specifically, I am wondering about the first paragraph of the Warder class feature Defensive Focus. It grants Combat Reflexes using the character's Intelligence score instead of Dexterity. If I already have the normal Combat Reflexes feat then later on take a level of Warder, which version of Combat Reflexes takes priority?

Answer (score 5):

You have them both. You choose which one you use.

In general, things that overlap are always chosen by the owner (and thus you use whichever is best for the owner).